# I was recommended to accept an answer before it was possible

Tags: bug, status-declined, user-interface, new-users, accepted-answer

When voting up an answer to a recently asked question, you are reminded that you can/should accept the answer even though the time limit isn't up yet.

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

From [this question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1548/you-can-select-an-answer-prompt-shown-before-you-really-can) on meta.SU.

Comment: which time limit? the two days limit is only for accepting your *own* answer, not for others

Comment: @tobias he's probably referring to the 15 minute minimum accept time.

Comment: @Jeff I didn't know about that... But I never had the luck of such [a helpful answer within 5 minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3862098/timeline) on the other hand

Comment: @Jeff I sure was :) - Do you think it's a bug?

Comment: ~bug. Found the same on superuser.com http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1548/you-can-select-an-answer-prompt-shown-before-you-really-can

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't view this as a bug.

We're just letting you know the capability is there. And just because you get an answer within 10 minutes doesn't mean it's a *good idea* to accept it so early.

Fine as-is.