# Vote up popup vs Select answer popup

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I was recommended to accept an answer before it was possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66654/i-was-recommended-to-accept-an-answer-before-it-was-possible)

I got a great answer to my question, and wanted to accept it, as well as upvote.  I upvoted first, and a popup alerted me that I could also click the checkmark below to choose that as an answer.  I then clicked the checkmark, and another popup told me that I couldn't select that as answer for another two minutes.  Can we add the information from the second popup to the first?  I'm normally a pretty amiable guy, but I can see other users getting frustrated at the contradiction.