# How to encourage users to accept answers

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

Some time ago users' *accept rate* has been removed from their flair. I can understand the rationale behind [this decision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate) (even if I disagree), so I won't discuss it here.

From my point of view, this has made a problem even more evident. Many users (more because no one tells them they have to accept some answer) will forget to do it (or they just don't care) and they'll ask questions again and again (I don't want to talk about reasons for this behavior).

Accepted answers are an important part of Stack Overflow (both to help future visitors with the same problem find the right answer, and to encourage newbies to answer a question).

What I suggest is to **strongly** encourage OPs to accept answers. Let's say that a user with a too small accept rate (but with a high number of questions) can't ask more questions. I would consider a delay as warning (wait 30 seconds before you can post your question if you're near that threshold).

Why this? Because [accepted answers are an important part of Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163740/actually-how-important-is-accepting-an-answer-to-the-stack-exchange-model/163743#163743): they help future readers to quickly find what works (votes are often not enough). They help who is looking for open questions to skip them. They give an extra *compensation* (not right word, I know) for whom answered.

If accepted answer is an *old* concept (and down/up votes are more important) then I think it should be dropped (or its name changed to something more meaningful). Of course I think it shouldn't so users must be educated to use it.

Comment: Please explain **why** people not accepting answers is a bad thing? What exactly is the problem with it (considering that **upvotes** are how the community tells good answers from bad)?

Comment: @Oded no, I maean: if their accept rate is low (belowe an arbitrary threshold plus some rules) then they can't ask a new questions.

Comment: Why? What does that solve? What problem? You seem to correlate low accept rate with low quality questions - if so, I'd like to see the data you base this on.

Comment: @Adriano whose fault is it if they don't get acceptable answers? I wish someone could promise me acceptable answer on each and every of my questions...

Comment: @Oded sorry if I've not been clear. No, questions may be even high quality. I mean that many users don't care to accept answers. That's why I would stop them to ask if they don't improve accept rate.

Comment: I will ask again then - **why is this a problem?**; You are asking for a change but have not demonstrated the concrete **benefit** (say we do so and more people accept answers - **why is that good?**)

Comment: @Mołot just "roam around": you'll see comments like "thank you, it helped" but answer isn't accepted. Other times just silence but answer is obviously right.

Comment: @Oded because accepted answers are a main part of SO! They highlight what works. They help to highlight right solution (for others). They stop users to browse that question to provide a new answer.

Comment: No. **Upvotes** and **downvotes** are the main part. **That** is what you should look at - not the **subjective** check mark that an OP uses to mean "I have found this to help me most". I have seen accepted answers that were completely wrong and other answers on the same question that were right had many more upvotes.

Comment: @Adriano If I see comment like that, I kindly ask OP what this answer is lacking and how it needs to be improved to get an "accept" mark from him. If you are willing to provide acceptable answers for users, simply do the same!

Comment: @Oded right but on the other side even votes aren't enough to highlight what works (I have a recent question where most upvoted answer was just...completely wrong). I think if SO keeps "accepted answer" concept then it should be encouraged otherwise it may be simply dropped.

Comment: @Mołot IMO then we risk to go back to same issues we had when accept rate was in flair. I really think that if SO has this concept then it has to be enforced. If it's not important then it should be dropped (or name changed to something more meaningful).

Comment: @Adriano I agree - SO should enforce that all askers gets an acceptable answer. Idea is great. But how to force answerers to write that answers? Who to punish for the fact that question is unanswered or answerers didn't worked quite to the asker's satisfaction? How and who to force to write acceptable answers where there are none yet?

Comment: @Mołot Here I agree with [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136961/187893). Questions without answers aren't counted for accept rate. Do you really think that (random numbers for an example) an user with 50 questions and 5 accepted answers...didn't find satisfaction for at least 50/75%? It may happen (1:1000000) then he can contact a moderator to be unlocked...

Comment: Yep, it is well possible he didn't. Especially if he uses less popular tag / technology or if his setup is so uncommon hardly anyone can or bothers to give answers tailored to that setup. So why don't do this another way around? Like "you posted 50 answers, but only 5 was accepted - please improve your existing answers, unless your answers are more acceptable, you can't post new answers". Wouldn't this make sense for you?

Comment: [ChrisF described some reasons why it might matter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163743/179419) @Oded, nothing to do with the OP but the perception of how a SE site works. If you re-run the query in my question the incidence of acceptance has continue to drop. If acceptance doesn't matter then it doesn't matter but if it does...

Comment: @Mołot I would prefer something like that, of course but...I suppose it's like that now (and it doesn't work so well, IMO).

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards there is no way to tell what % of the "accept" marks was there just to get rid of "accept more" comments, and what % was honest. If acceptance is really supposed to mean "it solved my problem", and not "I was tired of comments about low accept rate", then the drop is a *good* thing.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards thank you for link, yes nice question!

Comment: Also true @Molot, the question seeks/ed to find out whether or not it is important. As I say, it might not be :-).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace accept rate with citizenship level](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165179/replace-accept-rate-with-citizenship-level)

Comment: @gnat no, I wouldn't reintroduce accept rate (even if I like citizenship level idea). I would _force_ users that had benefit from community to contribute back (not only with good questions). I would stop them to ask questions if they don't work on accepted answers (50/75% accept rate is pretty fair).

Comment: And how do you ensure that 75% of my questions will get an answer that will actually solve my issue, again? I think I missed that part...

Comment: @Adriano the point of citizenship level, as I understand it, is one can look at its value and figure if the user abstaining of accept does this consciously (ie they have sufficient experience) or it makes sense to educate them about how site works, if they have low experience ("low citizenship level")

Comment: @Mołot of course you can't. That's why there should be an _Request to unlock_ button. That said I can't imagine an user with 20 (or more) questions and no good answers (if he doesn't forget to accept answer then probably he should improve way he asks). Examples (not theory) are welcome!

Comment: @gnat yes, that's why I like it. It's kind of _reminder_ that you're part of a community.

Comment: @Adriano so you will not guarantee 75% of my questions will get acceptable answers, but you want to force me to accept answers anyway? So you want to force me to start to lie to the community? Because if only 50% of my questions will get acceptable answers, and I have to post accept marks on 75% of them, then checkmarks on 25% of my questions would be a lie.

Comment: @Mołot no. Threshold can be 50%. Even 25%. In practice you'll have answers. In case not...just ask to be unlocked and you'll go on to ask unanswered questions. For 95% of users who simply forget to accept an answer this will work as reminder (as _tests_ when you do review).

Comment: @Adriano No matter what the threshold is, if you can't guarantee that the same or higher % of answer will actually get an acceptable answer, you are forcing some users to lie, and diminish the value of acceptance, as it becomes less trustworthy. Reminders, yes. Forced thresholds, no.

Comment: @Mołot no, they don't have to lie. If their satisfaction is really so low then they don't have to lie, just ask to be unlocked (by a moderator).

Comment: If you accept that they did nothing wrong, why to punish them at all? And why to bother moderators?

Comment: @Mołot because accepted answer are an important part of SO! See link in my question for Ben's post.

Comment: They are important enough to make users post them at random to avoid autoban? It seems a strange idea to wreck a tool for the very reason it is important. You usually don't want this, quite the opposite.

Answer (score 5):

It is already encouraged using two things:

1. You get 2 rep points if you accept an answer.
2. There is a badge that you can earn when you accept an answer for the first time.

Comment: I know but this doesn't help enough (just look stats of accepted answers). For the badge you just need one accepted answer. IMO for too many users when you solved your problem then you're OK (they don't care - sorry if this sounds too strong - about community itself).

Comment: As far as I remember there is even popup that appear when you upvote an answer, telling you that you can mark it as accepted. Yep, [found it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66654/152859).

Comment: @ShadowWizard who said they'll upvote? LOL

Comment: @Adriano well, upvoting is a more obvious action. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Not if the OP has less than 15 rep.

Answer (score 4):

Accepted answers are often *not* a good thing, and I, for one, would be happy if they went away.

All too often, ignorant or quirky askers accept answers that are wrong. Yet that big green check influences positioning on the page and behavior. We have to hope that google searchers actually figure out that 'the big green check means that the person with the aluminum foil hat liked the rhyme scheme of this answer; if you want to know what the *community* thought, stick with the vote totals'

Comment: I may even agree to completely remove "accepted answer" concept, especially when they're misused (or half ignored). If (according to Ben's statistics) only half questions has an accepted answer then they're going to be even more confusing. I just can't imagine how SO can be refactored to remove them...